# Textbox validation, cursor skipping to the start of the text

Tags: vb.net, string, validation, textbox

In vb.net, I have the following code to validate acceptable characters that can be entered into a textbox.

```
Private Sub txt_mobile_phone_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_mobile_phone.TextChanged

    Dim s As String = ""

    For Each C As Char In txt_mobile_phone.Text
        If (C >= "0" And C <= "9") OrElse (C = " ") OrElse (C = "-") OrElse (C = "+") Then
            s &= C
        End If

    Next
    txt_mobile_phone.Text = s

End Sub
```

The problem is, is that when someone enters an invalid character (for example, an exclamation mark '!'), the cursor position then skips to the start of the text string, and all further characters are entered at the start.Is there a way to make it so that it ignores invalid characters and carries on typing from the end of the string?

If possible, without using `txt_mobile_phone.SelectionStart = txt_mobile_phone.Text.Length -1` as this means that clicking the middle of the string to add to the middle of it will break (which currently is possible)

Comment: You should not be handling the `TextChanged` event for validation.  If you want to prevent the user entering particular characters at all then you should be handling `KeyPress`, `KeyDown` or `PreviewKeyDown` depending on specifics and if you want to validate after the fact then you should be handling `Validating`.  Any time you set the `Text` property you are first wiping out what was there before, thus losing the caret position, and then adding the new text.  DO NOT change the `Text` in the `TextChanged` event handler.

Comment: You say "without using `txt_mobile_phone.SelectionStart = txt_mobile_phone.Text.Length -1`". This would not work anyway, it would break the program as soon as all text is deleted, due to the `SelectionStart` being 0-1 = -1, and it cannot start from here

Comment: @jmcilhinney So, if I move the code into `KeyPress`, it will solve the problem naturally?

Comment: @David - Unless he adds it in a try statement

Comment: You can't just move that code into another event handler and expect it to work.  You have to write code appropriate for that event.  The keyboard events I mentioned are all raised BEFORE the input is added to the current text, so it's prevention rather than cure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are firing an event on the TextChanged, that is int he middle of something. For your purpose, to validate entries, you have got the KeyPress event, whereby you have the `e.Handle` to block entries.

Find the example below, which I applied in my application to accept only numeric and should not accept spaces;

```
Private Sub txt_mobile_phone_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txt_mobile_phone.KeyPress, _
                                                                                                              AcEmpNo.KeyPress
    ' Accept only numeric values
    If (e.KeyChar < Chr(48) OrElse e.KeyChar > Chr(57)) _
    AndAlso e.KeyChar <> Chr(8) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

You can also use Char convertor if you don't know the code like;

```
e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Space)
```

Hope this helps.